# How to do string interpolation in scala with more than 22 arguments

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use string interpolation to convert a string in following format to case class.

```scala
CptEventPro(EmEventCptDetail(21669260,215106571,12002,1,Some(1),Some(2),None,None,None,None,test@gmail.com,2021-07-24 23:42:34.0,None,None,None,None,None,None,68,false,Some(2019-11-21 00:00:00.0)),EmEventCptDos(0,None,Some(),Some(0),Some(),Some(0),Some(),Some(0),Some(),None,None,Some(0),Some(),Some(0),Some(),Some(),Some(),Some(),None,Some(),Some()),EmEventFacProvider(Some(test),None,None,Some(0),Some(),Some(),None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None))
```

and I used following code to convert a string to case class.

```scala
def parse(str: String): CptEventPro = {
        str match {
            case s"CptEventPro(EmEventCptDetail($id,$encounterId,$procedureNum,$procedureQty,$procedureModifier1,$procedureModifier2,$procedureDate,$chargeCodeSelect,$procedureProvider,$midProvider,$userId,$userTimeEntered,$qaProcedureNum,$qaProcedureQty,$qaProcedureModifier,$qaProcedureProvider,$qaUserId,$qaUserTimeEntered,$workItemId,$specialist,$eventDos),EmEventCptDos($qaDisagree,$qaNote,$qaType,$qaDisagreeEmModifier1,$qaNoteEmModifier1,$qaDisagreeEmModifier2,$qaNoteEmModifier2,$qaDisagreeQty,$qaNoteQty,$qaDisagreeDatePerformed,$qaNoteDatePerformed,$qaDisagreePhysician,$qaNotePhysician,$qaDisagreeMidProvider,$qaNoteMidProvider,$qaTypeEmModifier1,$qaTypeEmModifier2,$qaTypeQty,$qaTypeDatePerformed,$qaTypePhysician,$qaTypeMidProvider),EmEventFacProvider($billingProvider,$secondaryProvider,$residentProvider,$qaDisagreeResidentProvider,$qaNoteResidentProvider,$qaTypeResidentProvider,$modifier3,$qaDisagreeModifier3, $qaNoteModifier3,$qaTypeModifier3,$modifier4,$qaDisagreeModifier4, $qaNoteModifier4,$qaTypeModifier4))" =>
                CptEventPro(
                    EmEventCptDetail(
                        parseToInt(id), parseToInt(encounterId), procedureNum, parseToInt(procedureQty),
                        parseToOptionString(procedureModifier1), parseToOptionString(procedureModifier2), parseToOptionYmdDate(procedureDate),
                        parseToOptionString(chargeCodeSelect), parseToOptionString(procedureProvider), parseToOptionString(midProvider),
                        userId, userTimeEntered, parseToOptionString(qaProcedureNum), parseToOptionInt(qaProcedureQty), parseToOptionString(qaProcedureModifier),
                        parseToOptionString(qaProcedureProvider), parseToOptionString(qaUserId), parseToOptionString(qaUserTimeEntered), parseToInt(workItemId),
                        parseToBoolean(specialist), parseToOptionString(eventDos)
                    ),
                    EmEventCptDos(
                        parseToInt(qaDisagree),parseToOptionString(qaNote),parseToOptionString(qaType),parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeEmModifier1),parseToOptionString(qaNoteEmModifier1),
                        parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeEmModifier2),parseToOptionString(qaNoteEmModifier2),parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeQty),parseToOptionString(qaNoteQty),
                        parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeDatePerformed),parseToOptionString(qaNoteDatePerformed),parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreePhysician),parseToOptionString(qaNotePhysician),
                        parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeMidProvider),parseToOptionString(qaNoteMidProvider),parseToOptionString(qaTypeEmModifier1),parseToOptionString(qaTypeEmModifier2),
                        parseToOptionString(qaTypeQty),parseToOptionString(qaTypeDatePerformed),parseToOptionString(qaTypePhysician),parseToOptionString(qaTypeMidProvider)
                    ),
                    EmEventFacProvider(
                        parseToOptionString(billingProvider),parseToOptionString(secondaryProvider),parseToOptionString(residentProvider),parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeResidentProvider),
                        parseToOptionString(qaNoteResidentProvider),parseToOptionString(qaTypeResidentProvider),parseToOptionString(modifier3),
                        parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeModifier3), parseToOptionString(qaNoteModifier3),parseToOptionString(qaTypeModifier3),
                        parseToOptionString(modifier4),parseToOptionInt(qaDisagreeModifier4), parseToOptionString(qaNoteModifier4),parseToOptionString(qaTypeModifier4)
                    )
                )
        }
    }
```

Now it show error on compile

`too many arguments for unapply pattern, maximum = 22`

Please help to convert the string to respective case class

Comment: I strongly suggest that you add more structure to your data rather than have a huge number of elements in a single class. There must be some link between some of that values so they can be grouped. Put that group in another class that can then be added as a single value in the main class.

Comment: Isn't there any way to parse above string to Case Class? I'm asking this because I can't change the structure

Comment: There are ways to so this but that case class needs serious refectoring and I would suggest that you reorganise your code.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can:

- split your initial string `str` in 3 substrings representing the 3 inner case classes
- and apply the same logic to parse from `String` to case class on each inner case class.

---

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here but maybe using a more "standard" representation like JSON would simplify a lot your code as parsing would just be JSON deserialization.

Comment: Also there's a possibility of comma in between the string. Any possible idea to split the string into 3 inner case class?

Comment: You can find the index of each case class name in the string and split at these indexes

Comment: If that's a possibility, I strongly suggest taking Gaël's advice and use a standard serialization format like JSON. There is no reason to reinvent the wheel and do serialization yourself when you could be focusing your energy on more interesting problems.